# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Hi i'm getting issue while running `./gradlew assembleRelease` after upgrading React native version 0.64 to 0.67,  and upgraded gradle version 4.2.1 to 7.1.2, please help me to fix this issue.

```
Task :library:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
  
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':library:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/vv/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8e1dbca81dfad29f4aee913d13f7c843/transformed/core-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

app/build.gradlew

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        kotlinVersion = "1.4.32"
        kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
        dokka_version = '0.10.1'
        androidxCoreVersion = '1.7.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
          classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue. Changing Gradle back to 4.2.1 will solve the issue. I think something you depend on is built with an older compileSdkVersion that doesn't work with newer Gradle versions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a proper solution, but I had the same problem and I solved it by adding '`app:`' like this:

```
gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

Hope this helps :)